# Why Harley & Jake say this words "Not Nice" in this situation?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Romance-Comedy movie *It's Complicated*, Jake having lunch with his ex-wife Jane & her children (age above 20).

> Gabby: Okay, I would like to say something, too. For real. No offense
>   to the lovely *Agness* or her charming offspring...
>
> Jake: **Not Nice**.
>
> Harley: **Not Nice**.

Gabby is daughter for Jane & Harley is Lauren's (also daughter for Jane) husband.
*Agness* is present wife for Jake. In this situation Gabby hasn't completed her sentence. But Harley & Jake responded by say with this words "Not Nice". Why so?

There is no offense in Gabby words. then why it is **not nice** to say this words then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gabby *says* "no offence", this usually means there *will* be something that is (or could be) offending following.

For example:

> No offence, but that dress looks really cheap.

In this case, "her charming offspring" is insulting, because it is clearly sarcastic. You would not normally, in a casual conversation, refer to someone's children as "charming offspring", so this is a sarcastic "compliment", meaning she thinks that Agness' children are not charming at all.

The reactions indicate that Jake and Harley think it is "not nice" to talk badly about the children of your ex-husband's new wife.